# upload an app on Apple Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my app on Apple Store, it gives me error in build as it doesn't show the plus (+) sign next to build word.

Apple Store website

[image: iTunes Connect website]

Answer (score 0):

At there clearly mention, you have to upload build using `XCode` or `Application Loader`

You can upload with that tool.

Comment: how , it is the first time I upload an app to Apple Store so can you clarify your solution @iOS Dev

Comment: You can upload via XCode here is the apple link : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html

Answer (score 0):

After uploading wait for some time. It will take some time for processing your IPA file. Try to relogin 10 to 20 minutes after uploading the build.  And prefer Application Loader to upload IPA with Apstore Certificate or Distribution certificate.